# dropCollection not working. Still see collections

Tags: mongoose

The following code should drop all connections but I see that subsequent call to `collections` returns collections which should be empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
const collectionsBeforeDrop = await db.collections();
    collectionsBeforeDrop.forEach(async (c) => {
      console.log(`got collection name : ${c.collectionName}`);
      await db.dropCollection(c);
    });
    console.log(`checking after cleanup`)
    const collectionsAfterDrop = await db.collections();
    collectionsAfterDrop.forEach(c => {
      console.log(`got collection name after claanup! THIS SHOULDN'T HAVE HAPPENED : ${util.inspect(c.collectionName)}`); //THIS CODE HITS
      throw new Error("couldn't clean up after test case");
    });
```

Output

```
cleaning up                                                                                                                

      at Object.log (test/question.test.js:61:13)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    got db [object Object]                                                                                                     

      at Object.log (test/question.test.js:64:13)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    truncating collections of db Questions                                                                                     

      at Object.log (test/question.test.js:67:13)

  console.log
    got collection name : areas

      at log (test/question.test.js:72:15)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    checking after cleanup                                                                                                     

      at Object.log (test/question.test.js:75:13)

  console.log                                                                                                                  
    got collection name after claanup! THIS SHOULDN'T HAVE HAPPENED : 'areas'

      at log (test/question.test.js:78:15)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `async` within a `forEach` loop, because `forEach` do not wait for the `await`.

So what happens is that your `forEach` loop fires multiple async calls to drop the collections, and then immediately goes to `collectionsAfterDrop`. So at this time, the collections are not yet dropped.

So to fix your issue, you can change your code to:

```
const collectionsBeforeDrop = await db.collections();

for (const collection of collectionsBeforeDrop) {
  console.log(`got collection name : ${c.collectionName}`);
  await db.dropCollection(c);
}

// will reach here only after all collections are removed

console.log(`checking after cleanup`)

const collectionsAfterDrop = await db.collections();

for (const collection of collectionsAfterDrop) {
  console.log(`got collection name after claanup! THIS SHOULDN'T HAVE HAPPENED : ${util.inspect(c.collectionName)}`); //THIS CODE HITS
  throw new Error("couldn't clean up after test case");
}
```